# Trying to perform two operations on a single huge source file to gain performance

Tags: shell-script, pipe

I am performing two operations in a single Linux command. The operations are:

1. Sending data from source file into a new target file.
2. Counting the number of records in the source file.

For example: source file: `a.txt`, target file: `b.txt`

```
cat a.txt > b.txt; cat a.txt | wc -l
```

In the above example, I extract data from `a.txt` twice to perform the two operations. However, my source file is very huge. So for better performance, I am trying to find a way to extract data from source file just once and perform both the operations.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

`tee` is the command you're looking for:

```
cat a.txt | tee b.txt | wc -l
```

Also, as suggested in the comments, if you want something shorter you can avoid using `cat` entirely and redirect `a.txt` straight into `tee`'s stdin:

```
tee b.txt < a.txt | wc -l
```

From [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html):

> `tee` - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

Comment: `tee b.txt <a.txt | wc -l`.  No need for the `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

To get both actions in one file read you can do:

```
awk '++c;END{print c >"/dev/stderr"}' <a.txt >b.txt
```

Understand that the count will come from `stderr`.